# evaluate CNN model for occlusion detection on cityperson dataset

Tags: tensorflow, testing, annotations, object-detection, occlusion

how can i evaluate my model trained on Cityperson dataset, for occlusion. I have the images of test set but not annotations
Thanks

i expect to receive an explanation of how to evaluate the model for occlusion detection on cityperson dataset